# Converting an UTF-16 index to a UTF-8 compatible one

Tags: utf-8, utf-16

I am currently working with the Telegram API, and in one of [its methods](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#messageentity) it returns the following information:

- a piece of text
- offset in UTF-16 Code Units
- length in UTF-16 Code Units

In my programming language, Rust, all strings are valid UTF-8. This means that UTF-16 offsets are not immediately useful as they can be off by a variable amount (due to 1 or 3 byte code points). A one-byte code-point in UTF-8 corresponds to a two-byte one in UTF-16, so I cannot simply index the UTF-8 string as I may lay outside of code-point boundaries.

I am wondering now: Is there a way to convert it to valid UTF-8 without iterating through the UTF-8 string or if the information is useless once in UTF-8?

Comment: I did not tag Rust, as it is only incidentally related to the question

Comment: This is a funny interface. The text is transmitted in UTF-8 but offsets are in UTF-16. This probably makes sense for Java and .NET programmers that will convert the text into a string, which internally uses UTF-16. In Rust, you will have to iterate through the string (or convert it into an UTF-16 array). Due to the variable length nature of UTF-8, only UTF-8 offsets work to directly access part of an UTF-8 string without iteration.

Comment: How is a code point > 0xFFFF encoded? Which such interface (and you say 1 to 3 [not 4] bytes), I would suspect that each code **unit** is translated to UTF-8. Could you check it? Note: strictly speaking such UTF-8 is not a valid Unicode string: you get not correct code point, but maybe it is ok-ish to code surrogates as code points [numerically allowed by UTF-8, but results is not Unicode string]

Comment: In any case, it is necessary to iterate, but you should do it anyway, for security reasons: you do not want to receive degenerate UTF-8 (and in general degenerate sequence of Unicode code points). Filters may not works in such cases (e.g. UTF-8 implementations have various aliases of `NUL`)

Comment: UTF-16 either needs 2 or 4 bytes for one character - in doubt expect Telegram to always assume only 2 bytes. You can test this by requesting Emojis (should need 4 bytes per character) and then see if "offset" and "length" are really appropriate.

Comment: **Both** UTF-8 and UTF-16 are ***variable-length** encodings* of Unicode. Whilst both of these [*U*nicode *T*ransfomation *F*ormat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#UTF) forms provide a means to convey text in the form of "codepoints" even those do not necessarily mean what the user might recognised as a "character". The correct term is probably "grapheme", which is the *quantum* of text, i.e. a single representational "unit" - however those can, like graphemes including *combining diacriticals*, or *flags* use more than one codepoint to convey the grapheme that represents them.